# Handling select list to trigger an event when changing selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm setting up complaints managment system , and when it comes to a list of complaints, i want to give each row of a table a way to change a person who is currently handling this, i set up select menu already that get's all employees and then when i select any of them from the list this should be a trigger for my future script.

i have tried .change fuction .trigger with no luck

```
var pracownicy = [];
    $('#pobierz').click(function() { 
    //
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"pobierz_pracownikow.php",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:'json', 
            async:false,

            success: function(json) {


                for(var klucz in json)
                    {
                        var wiersz = json[klucz];
                        var pracownik={id:wiersz[0],dane_pracownika:wiersz[1]};
                        pracownicy.push(pracownik);
                    }
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(pracownicy));
                //console.log(pracownicy.length);
                //console.log(pracownicy[0].dane_pracownika);
            },

            error: function(blad) {
                alert( "Wystąpił błąd");
                console.log(blad); 
            }
    });
```

then using this array to make select list

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET", 
    url:"pobierz.php", 
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:'json', 

        success: function(json) {

            var tablice="<table id='tablePreview' class='table table-sm table-hover'><thead><tr><th>NR reklamacji</th><th>Ilość reklamacji</th><th>Klient</th><th>Osoba zajmująca się</th> <th>Dokument</th><th>Nazwa Firmy</th> <th>Data</th> <th>Kierowca</th></tr></thead>";

            for (var klucz in json)
                {
                    var wiersz = json[klucz];  
                    var nr = wiersz[0];
                    var ile = wiersz[1];
                    var klient = wiersz[2];
                    var pracownik = wiersz[3];
                    var fv = wiersz[4];
                    var firma = wiersz[5];
                    var data = wiersz[6];
                    var kierowca = wiersz[7];

                        lista_prac="<select class='browser-default custom-select selectpicker'>";
                        //  tablice+="<option selected>"+pracownik+"</option>";
                        for(var i=0;i<pracownicy.length;i++)
                            {
                            lista_prac+="<option ";
                            //console.log(pracownik+" "+pracownicy[i].dane_pracownika);
                            if(pracownik==pracownicy[i].dane_pracownika)
                            {
                                lista_prac+="selected";
                            }
                            lista_prac+=" id="+nr+" value='"+pracownicy[i].id+"'>"+pracownicy[i].dane_pracownika+"</option>";
                            }
                        lista_prac+="</select>";

                    tablice+="<tr><td>"+nr+" </td><td> "+ile+"</td><td> "+klient+"</td><td>"+lista_prac+"</td><td> "+fv+"</td> <td> "+firma+"</td> <td> "+data+"</td> <td> "+kierowca+"</td></tr>";

                } 
            tablice+="</tbody></table><br>";

            $('#wykaz').append(tablice);
```

i'm not getting any feedback from the console, just like it was never triggered. Can this be caused by printing data dable with selection list using ajax?

Comment: Can you please provide your html as well?

Comment: the whole html involved into this is contained in var tablice, in js file, then i just append whole thing into empty  `<div id="wykaz"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used
`function changeval(sel)
{ alert(sel.value);}`
outside of `$(document).ready(function()` and called the function inside select button and it is working